# jquery fade-ins, fade-outs piling up

Tags: jquery

I have some jquery ajax that, when it returns, and depending on the result of the operation, fades in and fades out various DIV messages on the page. For example:

```
$("#RefConflictSelf").fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(6000);
```

I like this effect and I want to keep it.

This works fine when users wait at least 7 seconds before clicking another button to trigger another ajax operation. But if they go through clicking buttons one after another (a legitimate thing to do actually) the divs fading in and out start piling up, so that you see these divs fade in and fade out for several previous operations that users no longer care about.

Summary: By the time a user clicks the 2nd button, they no longer care about the fadein/fadeout of the div from the 1st/previous button click.

Question: Is there a way to IMMEDIATELY hide any "fading in or fading out" divs, but still correctly fade in the message for the latest button click?

I already tried this: whenever a button is clicked I immediately hide all message divs, for example:

```
$("#RefConflictSelf").hide();
```

This sort of works, but it's clumsy, because if you click 5 buttons 1 after another, newer div messages will remain invisible until the original one would have faded out. So the ".hide()" seems to stomp on the newer "fade in" operations, until the fade time of the original (or latest non-stomped one) has elapsed, and it's all done.

How do I make jquery hide all previous fading div messages, but then allow the newest div message to fade in, then out, as normal? (Unless of course another button is then clicked, in which case the old one should be stomped, and the new one be allowed to work.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why your animation is piling up is because `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` are being added to the animation queue at a faster rate than they can be actually cleared (7 seconds for a pair, based on your durations). Therefore, you need to clear the queue before calling a new fading animation.

This is done by using  `stop(true)`, which is a short for `stop(true,false)`, instruction jQuery to (1) clear the queue but (2) not jump to the end state of animation:

```
$("#RefConflictSelf").stop(true).fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(6000);
```

Depending on the effect you want to achieve, sometimes `stop(true,true)` might suit your needs better, as it instructs clearing of the queue *and* jumping to the final state of the current queued animation(s).

---

Although you have not shown your markup, based on your question:

> How do I make jquery hide all previous fading div messages, but then
>   allow the newest div message to fade in, then out, as normal? (Unless
>   of course another button is then clicked, in which case the old one
>   should be stomped, and the new one be allowed to work.)

... I have a feeling that you are recycling IDs. Remember that **IDs** must be unique in a HTML document. Browser behavior for handling multiple identical IDs by definition remains undefined, but it will typically (intelligently, sort of) pick the first occurrence and ignore the rest.

p/s: I happen to [write an article why `.stop()` is very useful](https://medium.com/coding-design/how-to-stop-writing-bad-jquery-animations-f1481782dc4e) when dealing with jQuery animations <strike>some months</strike> a year ago.

Comment: He might also want [`.finish`](http://api.jquery.com/finish/) if he wants it the state to jump to the end of all queued actions.

Comment: Terry, you're a hero. It works perfectly. BTW I was not reusing IDs so that part was fine. Your original suggestion solved it for me: $("#RefConflictSelf").stop(true).fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(6000);